# MSDTC - adding a 3rd node to a windows cluster

Tags: sql, sql-server

Have an active/active sql cluster (2005) on windows 2003 to which we're adding a 3rd node.   What would we need to do to add the new node as a failover site for msdtc? Can we add the node as a possible in cluster administrator or is there more to it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the batch script that I wrote to do this (it's old but still good), you should be able to just set your new node as a possible owner of the msdtc group once it's added to the cluster.  My script has the following:

```
cluster cluster_name group "MSDTC Group" /setowners:nodeA,nodeB,nodeC
```